# Как сделать соответствие сертификата сервера и URL?

Tags: url

На только что созданном сайте выскакивает сообщение, **что подключение не защищено**. В адресной строке **перечеркнут значок замка и https**, также *написано, что идентификационные данные этого сайта не проверены. Сертификат сервера не соответствует URL*.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Ну так может добавите описание - что за сертификат вы ставите, какой серв, настройки и прочее. Может у вас сертификат такой

Answer (score 1):

Доменное имя сайта должно совпадать с указанным в сертификате (Common Name), проще всего бесплатно получить и обновлять подписанный с помощью доверенного центра сертификации через LetsEncrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/

```
  git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
  cd letsencrypt/
  ./letsencrypt-auto
```

Также можно будет перечислить и другие доменные имена (alias), которые могут использоваться на данном сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидный ответ: выпустить с помощью доверенного центра сертификации (*Comodo*, *Thawte*, *VeriSign* и т.п.) сертификат, соответствующий имени сайта и "подпихнуть" его веб-серверу.